# Type Error property undefined even though action fired off defining it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I am currently having a button redirect to the same location a button on a prior dashboard takes you to it is essentially a render of a graph and all of its notes and questions rendered. Now the specific snippet in the error works from my initial location which is denoted below in my screenshot that speculation button will take you to the rendered show route below it. However, the button that appears after you have made a new question and note do not they use the same snippet but one errors out I am also adding the snippet for the buttons.

*edit 1 adding show.js

```
show.js

// built-in(lifecycle) methods imported here
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// import components from local 
import Graph from '../components/Graph'
import Notes from '../components/Notes'
import Questions from '../components/Questions'

//imbrl allows us to enable routing by updating url and rendering needed component listed in routeer
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

//bootstrap WIP
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'

// access state from redux store
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Show extends Component {

    render() {
    // variables for objects
    const graph = this.props.graphs.find(graph => { return graph.id === parseInt(this.props.match.params.id)})
    const notes = this.props.notes.filter(note => note.graph.id === graph.id)
    const questions = this.props.questions.filter(question => question.graph.id === graph.id)


    // if graph exists it loads all corresponding notes and questions with it
    if (graph) {

        return (
            <Row>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <Notes graph={graph} notes={notes} />
                </Col>

                <Col md={6} >
                    <Card>
                        <Graph graph={graph}/>
                    </Card>

                    <NavLink
                    to={`/graphs/${graph.id}/interact`}>
                        <Button>Interact</Button>
                    </NavLink>
                </Col>


                <Col md={3}>
                    <Questions graph={graph} questions={questions} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavLink
                style={{marginRight: '10px'}}
                to="/">
                <Button variant="dark" size="lg" block>Add Data to get started</Button>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
         )
        }
    }
}


// this will need access to the objects
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        graphs: state.graphs,
        notes: state.notes,
        questions: state.questions
    }
}


export default connect (mapStateToProps)(Show)
```

```
graphinput.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'

// import actions future?
import { addNote } from '../actions/addSpeculations'
import { addQuestion} from '../actions/addSpeculations'

// browser url routing render component as needed
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

// import local components
import Note from '../components/Note'
import Question from '../components/Question'

// bootstrap styling
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'

// allows access to redux store this is a stateful component
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class GraphInput extends Component {
// initial state placejolders 
    state ={
        note: {
            content: ""
        },
        question: {
            content: ""
        },
        visible: false,
        view: false
        }
        // state will be updated everytime the form value changes
        handleChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({
                [event.target.name]: {content: event.target.value, graph_id: this.props.graph_id}
            })
        }
        // visible key will show as true to confirm before calling fetch.
        handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            this.setState({visible: true})
        }

        handleSave = () => {
            this.props.addNote(this.state.note)
            this.props.addQuestion(this.state.question)
            this.setState({
                note: {content: ""},
                question: {content: ""},
                visible: false,
                view: true
            })

        }

        // if user cancels submission, state should reset to initial values
        handleCancel = () => {
            this.setState({
                note: {content: ""},
                question: {content: ""},
                visible: false,
                view: false
            })
        }

        render () {
            // Need to check current state to base what return should be used for what user interaction has done.
            /*const validated= this.state.note.content.length > 20 && this.state.note.content.length > 20*/

            if (this.state.visible === false && this.state.view === false){
                /// render form and graph
                return (
                    <div>
                            <h3> Add your Observations or Speculation below. </h3>

                        <Form onSubmit={event => this.handleSubmit(event)} >
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Control size="lg" type="text" name="note" placeholder="Make an observation." value={this.state.note.content} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)} />
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Control size="lg" type="text" name="question" placeholder="Ask a question" value={this.state.question.content} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)} />
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Button  type="submit" >Add</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </div>

                )
            } else if (this.state.visible === true && this.state.view === false) {
                /// rwendering draft to confirm submission
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Note note={this.state.note} />
                        <Question question={this.state.question} />
                        <Button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSave}> Save Speculation to Database</Button>
                        <Button type="submit" variant="danger" onClick={this.handleCancel}>Cancel</Button>
                    </div>
                )
            } else if (this.state.view === true) {
                // after saving, user can now navigate to view all 
                return (
                    <NavLink
                        style={{ marginRight: '10px'}, {backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                        to={`/graphs/${this.props.graph_id}/speculations`}
                        graph={this.props.graph}>
                        <Button size="lg" block>View All Speculation for This Graph</Button>
                    </NavLink>
                )
        }

    }
}


// only state needed is graph speculations  for specific graph
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        graph: state.graph
    }
}

// Dispatch to props for Notes and Questions
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addNote, addQuestion})(GraphInput)
```

```js
Broken Button
<NavLink
   style={{ marginRight: '10px'}, {backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
   to={`/graphs/${this.props.graph_id}/speculations`}
   graph={this.props.graph}>
  <Button size="lg" block>View All Speculation for This Graph</Button>
</NavLink>
```

```
 Working Button
                <NavLink
                    style={{ marginRight: '10px'}}
                    to={`/graphs/${this.props.graph.id}/speculations`}
                    url={this.props.graph.screenshot_url} >
                        <Button variant="success" >
                            Speculations
                        </Button>
                </NavLink>
```

[image: Error]

This is the button that works
[image: Working Speculation Button] 
This is where the button should take you
[image: Intended location after the button is clicked]
This button does not go to the show with that specific graph's notes and questions. (Both are using the same snippet to identify graph and its id or are supposed to)
[image: Not working button]

Comment: `this.props.notes` has an element which is undefined. Could you edit your post to include `Show.js` and the component that's using it?

Comment: Yes I understand that its undefined but I dont understand why it is if that information should be present in state as redux tools show it is. Sure I can add the show.js and the component.

Comment: I've added the components the logic is present in.